# Strange behaviour of c++ char buffers in a for loop

Tags: c++, loops, char

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,i;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<n<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        char x[3];
        cin>>x;
        cout<<x<<' '<<i<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To the above program if I give input as

```
2
X++
--X
```

The output turns out to be

```
2
X++ 0
--X 0
--X 1
```

I expected it to be

```
2
X++ 0
X-- 1
```

Later I understood what the mistake was and replaced `char x[3]` with `char x[4]` since strings are `null` terminated. But why was the above program working that way(I know C doesn't throw errors for overflows).

Comment: You can't store `"X++"` in a `char [3]`, you need an extra cell for the nul character.

Comment: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: *"I know C doesn't throw errors for overflows"* That's not true. C doesn't *define* what to do then, but a compiler/runtime *can choose* to throw an error. Also, C isn't C++ and you are using C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to store `"X++"` in a `char [3]` which is not possible because you need an extra cell for the `'\0'` character.

What happens is that `std::cin >>` does not care bout the size of your array and will write as many character as it can from the standard input (stopping at the first "space" character).

In this case, `std::cin >>` will write 4 characters (`X`, `+`, `+`, `\0`), thus erasing an extra byte of memory after the "end" of the variable `x`.

Likely, that extra byte of memory contained the value of your loop variable `i`, so you have modified the value of `i` inside the loop without knowing it.

Your code is not safe and has an [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), use `std::string` instead of `char []` in this case to avoid such behavior:

```
std::string x ;
std::cin >> x ;
```

---

Here is an example of how you memory could look like and what may happens (this is schematic, not real, just to explain):

At the beginning (`i = 0`, `x` has no value).

```
|-----x-----|-------i-------|
| . | . | . | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

At the end of the first loop:

```
|-----x-----|-------i-------|
| X | + | + | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

At the beginning of the second loop (I assumed big endian for `i`):

```
|-----x-----|-------i-------|
| X | + | + | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

At the end of the second loop:

```
|-----x-----|-------i-------|
| - | - | X | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

You can see that by writing `x`, I have changed the value of `i` from `1` to `0`.